# How to Redirect a user to a external login page and get response code after successful login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, axios

I have a link which when hit returns HTML of the login page.

https://somelink.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=someclientid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&response_type=code

Once this HTML is rendered on browser, user enters his username and is redirected to another page where user enters password. (https://dev.login.com)

After successful login, user is redirected to callback uri [http://localhost:3000/callback?code="somecode"](http://localhost:3000/callback?code=%22somecode%22). I need this code to make further requests to get access Token and refresh token.

So how should I proceed? The tech stack I'm using is React and Nodejs with Express. I tried this in Node by making get request to first url and then rendering response

```
const options = {
    url: "https://somelink.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=someclientid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&response_type=code",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  await axios(options)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('success');
      res.send(response['data']);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

the `res.send(response["data"])` opens the webpage using the HTML response from the get request. After entering username it makes a post request onto a /authorize page instead of the actual password entry page. I created a route for /authorize but not sure what I should include in it

How should I proceed? Should I be using React to make the requests?

Comment: This questions talks about too many problems. I can answer if you have completed all steps except the last one i.e. extracting `somecode` from this frontend (ReactJS App) URL - `http://localhost:3000/callback?code=somecode`. So, do you need an answer for this step?

Comment: Yeah, I know there are many problems mentioned. I just want a general approach I should take or maybe some link I could refer to. Extracting ```somecode``` shouldn't be a problem. Thanks anyways

Comment: My advice: Break this problem into many (3-4 or 4-5) small problems and solve each one by one. In that way, you will find that most of the sub-problems are already solved in some blogs or on stackoverflow.